# Close event is not triggered in JFace application

Tags: java, jface

I'm very new in JFace and I've some problems to understand why my close listener doesn't work.
I modified a simple JFace example:

```
public class JFaceExample extends ApplicationWindow {
  private ExitAction exitAction;

  public JFaceExample() {
    super(null);
    exitAction = new ExitAction(this);
    addMenuBar();
    addStatusLine();
    addToolBar(SWT.FLAT | SWT.WRAP);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configureShell(Shell shell) {
    super.configureShell(shell);
    shell.setText("JFace File Explorer");
    shell.addListener(SWT.Show, new Listener() {
      @Override
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        System.out.println("show");
      }
    });
    shell.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
      @Override
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        System.out.println("close");
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
    setStatus("JFace Example v1.0");
    return parent;
  }

  @Override
  protected MenuManager createMenuManager() {
    MenuManager menuBar = new MenuManager("");
    MenuManager fileMenu = new MenuManager("&File");
    MenuManager helpMenu = new MenuManager("&Help");
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    menuBar.add(helpMenu);
    fileMenu.add(exitAction);
    return menuBar;
  }

  @Override
  protected StatusLineManager createStatusLineManager() {
    StatusLineManager slm = new StatusLineManager();
    slm.setMessage("Hello, world!");
    return slm;
  }

  @Override
  protected ToolBarManager createToolBarManager(int style) {
    ToolBarManager toolBarManager = new ToolBarManager(style);
    toolBarManager.add(exitAction);
    return toolBarManager;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFaceExample fe = new JFaceExample();
    fe.setBlockOnOpen(true);
    fe.open();
    Display.getCurrent().dispose();
  }

  private class ExitAction extends Action {
    ApplicationWindow window;

    public ExitAction(ApplicationWindow w) {
      window = w;
      setText("E&xit@Ctrl+W");
      setToolTipText("Exit the application");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      window.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The show message is written to the console successfully. But if I click the exit menu item then the app is closed but no close message is written.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `window.close()` the shell close event is not fired, instead the shell is just disposed (so you could use a dispose listener on the shell).

There is a comment in the source code for this in the `close` code:

```
// If we "close" the shell recursion will occur.
// Instead, we need to "dispose" the shell to remove it from the
// display.
shell.dispose();
```

Comment: Hm, that's not so good because if I use the DisposeListener then I won't be able to prevent closing the shell, f.e. by asking for exit.

Comment: Ok, I found out that I can override the close method of the window class, do some tasks and returning true or false, depending whether I want to exit the program or not. The method is called everytime I execute Window.close(), clicking the close button on the GUI or closing the program by pressing Alt+F4 (Windows). That should solve my problem. It seems that Listeners are no longer necessary in JFace (for this purpose).